# How to dynamically flag a column in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have excel Data such as:

```
   Name                    Assets       Cluster    Flag
  ABN AMRO                 $100,000       2
  Allahabad Bank           $200,000       2
  Allen & Company          $50,000        1 
  Bank of America          $200,000       3 
  Barclays Capital         $300,000       3 
  BB&T                     $70,000        1
  BBY Ltd.                 $150,000       2
  Berkery, Noyes & Co.     $200,000       3
  BG Capital               $90,000        1
  Blackstone               $400,000       3
```

and so on, there are about 2000 records.

Now I have divided them into 3 clusters:

```
Cluster 1: Assets < $100,000
Cluster 2: 100,000 =< Assets < $200,000
Cluster 3: Assets >= 300,000
```

I want to use Excel, to basically do the following:

Flag a certain threshold of accounts in each cluster, which would be inputted by user.

For example, the user says only 5% of cluster 2 should be flagged, so the excel function should randomly flag "Yes" to 5% of the accounts in the Cluster 2 and so on. I want it to be interactive thats why I want user to input the parameter in a cell in excel, which would randomly change the value of flags next to the accounts in a cluster.
Is there any way I can achieve this in Excel?

Comment: Rank, Random and Large combined with conditional formatting will do that.

Comment: @cyboashu wow I really need to get more creative with native functions :)

Comment: @cyboashu I am a novice in excel, could you show me the function if it is possible?

Comment: Note that `RANK` is deprecated and only included for back-compatibility with 2007 & earlier. Also `RANDOM` will recalculate every time the sheet is modified, making the sheet behave rather weirdly. I'd go with some VBA.

Comment: With VBA: apply the filter on your range on the **cluster** you want. Then capture the result in an array. Apply `Randomise` on it to select random items. Use `Find` to set the flags on those items

Comment: @MathieuGuindon could you point me to some resources for this?

Comment: If you've never written any VBA code, you're about to enter a whole new world of possibilities... the subject is extremely broad though - I'd suggest searching for beginner-level tutorials, reading this site's [most frequently linked VBA questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) and their answers, and then of course *write some code*. What you're trying to accomplish involves a number of concepts (objects and arrays, particularly) that require a prior understanding of the language's basic syntax. What resources are "good" depend on where you stand =)

Comment: @Zac could you please show me how to do that? Sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column A: Name
Column B: Assets
Column C: Cluster
**Column D: Temp  (=Sort)

Column E: Flag**

Make a copy of your workbook. Open VBE (with Alt F11) and insert a module (Menu -> Insert -> Module). In the module you insert the code below and execute the procedure "main": Press F5 in Sub main()

```
Sub Main()
    'Put the cursor HERE and press F5.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ActCell As Range
    Set ActCell = ActiveCell

    Call CountTotals
    Call RandomNumber
    Call SortRandom
    Call SetFlag
    ActCell.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub CountTotals()
    Range("H8") = "Cluster"
    Range("H9") = 1
    Range("H10") = 2
    Range("H11") = 3

    Range("I8") = "Flag%"
    If Range("I9") = "" Then Range("I9") = "2%"
    If Range("I10") = "" Then Range("I10") = "5%"
    If Range("I11") = "" Then Range("I11") = "8%"

    Range("J8") = "Count"
    Range("J9:J11").FormulaR1C1 = "=Int(RC[-1]*RC[1])"

    Range("K8") = "Total"
    Range("K9").Formula = "=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$2001,""=1"")"
    Range("K10").Formula = "=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$2001,""=2"")"
    Range("K11").Formula = "=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$2001,""=3"")"
End Sub

Sub RandomNumber()
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Range("D2:D2001").Formula = "=int(rand()*1e6)"
    Range("D2:D2001").Copy
    Range("D2:D2001").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Sub SortRandomOLD()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "C2:C2001"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "D2:D2001"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:E2001")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Sub SortRandom()
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "C2:C2001"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "D2:D2001"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:E2001")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Sub SetFlag()
    Dim Cluster1Total As Integer
    Dim Cluster2Total As Integer
    Dim Cluster3Total As Integer

    Dim Cluster1Flag As Integer
    Dim Cluster2Flag As Integer
    Dim Cluster3Flag As Integer

    Cluster1Total = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C2001"), "=1")
    Cluster2Total = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C2001"), "=2")
    Cluster3Total = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C2001"), "=3")
    'Debug.Print Cluster1Total

    Cluster1FlagCount = Range("J9").Value
    Cluster2FlagCount = Range("J10").Value
    Cluster3FlagCount = Range("J11").Value

    Range("A1").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$2001").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1"
    Range("E2:E2001").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:C2,""=1"")<=" & Cluster1FlagCount & ",1,0)"

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$2001").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="2"
    Range("E2:E2001").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:C2,""=1"")<=" & Cluster2FlagCount & ",1,0)"

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$2001").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="3"
    Range("E2:E2001").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:C2,""=1"")<=" & Cluster3FlagCount & ",1,0)"

    Range("A1").AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: So I put this in the VBA script which I willl access from Developors tab? Can you please elaborate on how to execute this script? Thank you so much :)

Comment: That's the idea, yes ;-) I've tried to give you all the info you need above!

Comment: "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2").Sort.SortFields.Clear"

It shows runtime error on this Subscript out of range

Comment: Also, it is not generating any flags, I actually wanted a separate column as mentioned in the question, which gets flagged everytime I run the scripts.

Comment: I have replaced "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2")..." with "ActiveSheet...". (see above Sub SortRandom and Sub SortRandomOLD). In the column Flag you should get "1" for flagged items and "0" for not flagged ones.